# Ain't and negatives

Tags: word-usage, negation, contractions, informal-language

I am puzzled with the use of ain't. I know its meaning, and also know it is pretty informal. But I see it used in several ways, some I think of as conflicting.

See the following examples

---

> I ain't an idiot

expands to

> I am not an idiot

Which, in my understanding means "Well, I am declaring myself not an idiot"

---

> It just ain't done good

expands to

> It just is not done good

Which, in my understanding means "An action didn't generate good results"

---

> But I ain't marchin' anymore

expands to

> But I am not marching anymore

Which, in my understanding means "I am saying, that I will stop marching"

---

> Hey, ain't gonna cry no more today

expands to

> Hey, I am not going to cry no more today

This one is a bit weird, but in my understanding means "I am declaring my intentions of crying no more than I already did, today"

---

> I ain't no quitter

expands to

> I am not no quitter

Which, in my understanding means that "I am a quitter", since the first negation negates the second...

I really think it means "I am no quitter", but then "ain't" doesn't abbreviate the length of "am", so I don't get the usage of "ain't", or perhaps this phrase ain't a good example, even for an informal contraction like ain't.

Is it correct to use ain't followed by a no? Does the "no" lose its negation?

I really hope I ain't that confused by the answers...

Comment: "_I ain't an idiot_ expands to _I am not an idiot_ which, in my understanding means, _Well, I am declaring myself an idiot_." **Nope**. "I am not an idiot" means "I am _refuting_ that I'm an idiot. Had the original read, "I ain't **no** idiot", then that would expand to "I am not no idiot", which one _could_ interpret as "I am declaring myself an idiot," but it would probably still mean "I am not an idiot," with the double negative used for emphasis.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is double negation interpreted in English?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/829/how-is-double-negation-interpreted-in-english)

Comment: In the first example, it appears that you missed the word *not*.  In *it just ain't done good*, I think *good* likely functions as an adverb (which is nonstandard), giving the meaning *it just isn't done well*.  For the double negatives, see the question linked by FumbleFingers.

Comment: Yeah, I really understood correct the first example, but in copy paste I typed it wrongly. I'll let this way, so the comments and answers remains correct.

Comment: Just a remark -- in American English, "ain't" is lost even in extremely informal speech in the dialect of most speakers, with the notable exception of AAVE (I don't know about other countries). I don't recommend using it as a non-native speaker -- it won't make you sound informal, it will just sound weird.

Comment: @hunter Your comments are of very practical use. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let's be clear that *ain't* is not commonly used in proper and correct speech. It is a word, it is technically correct, and it does take the meaning of "[to be] not", as you have surmised. However it is most often used in uneducated speech, so you must be sure to take everything with a grain of salt when you see it used. I certainly wouldn't suggest you begin using it in formal contexts.

Let's begin with your first assertion:

> > I ain't an idiot
>
> expands to
>
> > I am not an idiot
>
> Which, in my understanding means "Well, I am declaring myself an idiot"

*Ain't* does indeed expand to *am not* here, but it certainly doesn't mean that the person thinks they *are* an idiot. They are quite clearly saying that they are *not* an idiot (probably in response to someone who has said they *are* one). *I am not [x]* is always a claim that a person is *not* something.

> > It just ain't done good
>
> expands to
>
> > It just have not done good
>
> Which, in my understanding means "An action didn't generated good results of if"

Now we return to my original point that *ain't* is often used in uneducated speech. The formal way to say this would be "It just is not done well." This means that [x] action (or the result of said action) has not been performed properly. For example, a teacher could be looking at a student's painting in an art class, and comment that the painting was not done (ie. not painted) well. But *ain't* doesn't expand to *have not* here, as you suggest; it expands to *is not* (simply another form of *[to be] not*).

> > But I ain't marchin' anymore
>
> expands to
>
> > But I am not marching anymore
>
> Which, in my understanding means "I am saying, that I will stop marching"

Your expansion to *am not* is correct, and you've almost got the interpretation down; what this means is *I am no longer marching. I have not been marching for some period time up until this point, and I will continue not to march.* The distinction from your interpretation is that they are not saying "I will stop marching from this point forward." They have *already* stopped marching.

> > Hey, ain't gonna cry no more today
>
> expands to
>
> > Hey, I am not going to cry no more today
>
> This one is a bit weird, but in my understanding means "I am declaring my intentions of crying no more that I already did, today"

Again we return to the issue of uneducated speech; the *ain't* is actually completely straightforward in this example, it does indeed expand to *am not*. However you have a different problem which is displayed in uneducated speech; that of the word *no* used when it ought to be *any*. This could have been correctly written *I ain't going to cry any more today* (expanding to *I am not going to cry any more today*). This means that at some point today they have cried a certain amount, and intend to not cry again for the rest of the day. They will not cry *any more* (or *any longer*).

> > I ain't no quitter
>
> expands to
>
> > I am not no quitter
>
> Which, in my understanding means that "I am a quitter", since be first negation negates the second...

This example has the same problem as the last one; the *ain't* is straight forward but the *no* is incorrect. It should read *I ain't a quitter* (expanded to *I am not a quitter*). Which, similar to your first example where the person professes to not be an idiot, means that the person denies any accusation that they might be a quitter.

So, overall, be careful with *ain't*. You've got a good handle on the expansion overall, but you have to watch out for the extra no/not negations you might find. Use context to help you as much as possible; rarely would someone claim to be a quitter or an idiot, so your best guess should be that it means the opposite :)

Comment: I'm sure I'm [*not telling you nothing*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22not+telling+you+nothing%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) you don't already know, but it ain't just a matter of being careful about *ain't*.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of a triple negative that was offered up in discussion of negatives on another site some years ago:

I ain't got no money. *I ain't never had no money*.

It means the person is the very opposite of a rich man.

Negatives in natural language are often used as intensifiers not reversers: they do not function like logical *nots*.

Answer (score 2):

"Ain't" is not Standard English.

Using double-negatives to express a negative (or an intense negative) is not Standard English.  In Standard English, double-negatives are either avoided, or are used to express complicated logic puzzles.

The same dialects that use "Ain't" also use double-negatives to express negatives and intense negatives.

Therefore, in many non-Standard English dialects, one could say:

> I ain't no quitter.

which expands to:

> I am not no quitter.  (In a dialect that uses double-negatives to express negatives)

and simplifies to:

> I am not a quitter.

Whereas in Standard English, one might say:

> I don't not quit.

which expands to:

> I do not (not quit).  (The parentheses are for explaining this logically; they would not be written out in real life.)

and simplifies to:

> I always quit.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, in English, a double negation results in no negation at all: both negatives cancel each other out (*it isn't not red = it is red*). In very informal or dialectical English, however, a double negation can instead be a strong negation (although it doesn't have to be: it can still result in no negation).

The word "ain't" is itself already very informal or dialectical. It can be used with "double negation = strong negation", but it can also be used simple, single negation. The context should make clear in which way it is used.

In most of your examples, both double-strong and single negation could have been used, they are mostly interchangeable in very informal English. I have made the double negatives resulting in strong negation **bold**:

> I ain't an idiot.

I am not an idiot.

> It just ain't done good.

It just hasn't/isn't done (any) good.

> But I ain't marchin' any more.

But I am not marching any more.

> Hey, ain't gonna cry **no** more today.

Hey, I am not going to cry any more today.

> I ain't **no** quitter.

I am no quitter.