# This doesn't seem to be a double negation, does it?

Tags: vocabulary

> They walked past a mossy tree stump. Harry could hear running water; there must be a stream somewhere close by. There were still spots of unicorn blood here and there along the winding path. 
>       "You all right, Hermione?" Hagrid whispered. "Don' worry, it can't've gone far if it's this badly hurt, an' then we'll be able ter –– GET BEHIND THAT TREE!" 
>       Hagrid seized Harry and Hermione and hoisted them off the path behind a towering oak. He pulled out an arrow and fitted it into his crossbow, raising it, ready to fire. The three of them listened. Something was slithering over dead leaves nearby: it sounded like a cloak trailing along the ground. Hagrid was squinting up the dark path, but after a few seconds, the sound faded away. 
>       "I knew it," he murmured. "There's summat in here that shouldn' be." 
>       "A werewolf?" Harry suggested. 
>       "**That wasn' no werewolf an' it wasn' no unicorn, neither**," said Hagrid grimly. "Right, follow me, but careful, now."
>       They walked more slowly, ears straining for the faintest sound. Suddenly, in a clearing ahead, something definitely moved. 
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

The bold part seems to be not a double negation but a dialect. Is this right?

Comment: Exactly - it is a negative doubled for emphasis.

Comment: @StoneyB, So those negative doubled can be sorted into two ways depending context: (1) just a dialect, (2) emphasis, can’t they?

Comment: Not exactly. There are **a)** double negations in **standard** formal usage, where NO + NO means YES, and **b)** double negations in dialect and other **non-standard** usage, where NO + NO means EMPHATICALLY NO.

Comment: I found a previous answer by StoneyB on the same topic: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/833/230