# Are double negatives like 'he's never not been in the family' grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, multiple-negation

I'm asking this question because I was taught not to use double negatives, because they are ungrammatical and that people who use them sound uneducated. However, today here on this site I found an answer with a double negative and asked my self is it correct to use double negatives? Well my doubts arose since this answer has eight positive votes. Even though I understand the meaning of it, I still wonder if it is correct or not. Below is the answer I'm talking about as well is the link to it.

Answer:

> "It might add the subtle extra nuance of meaning that since you were born he's never not been in the family."

Link: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/158385

P.S. Not trying to put this site and the people from it in doubt, just clarifying and making sure to learn well this beautiful language.

Comment: The "ungrammatical" ones are things like *I didn't do nothing*, and *We don't need no edookashun*, which are "illiterate, non-standard" idiomatic *intensifier* usages. Your cited example is "literal", so it doesn't fall into that category of "forms to avoid". Used sparingly, ***never not*** is a perfectly valid (if stylised) way of emphatically conveying the near-synonymous alternative ***always***.

Comment: Ok so what sould I do now delete my query?

Comment: Please don't delete your question - a duplicate is not as bad as it might sound. It just means that your question is very closely related to another question and that it makes sense to connect them together. I thought some of the answers of that other question may help you understand the topic a little better. There is some discussion on meta that might be helpful: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/3024/

Comment: From [*The Enemy of My Enemy* - The New York Times](http://goo.gl/hsa7Oo): "Likewise, double negatives don’t always amount to positives; they can make negatives more intense, as in “I can’t get no satisfaction.”  (... The eminent linguistic philosopher J. L. Austin of Oxford once gave a lecture in which he asserted that there are many languages in which a double negative makes a positive, but none in which a double positive makes a negative — to which the Columbia philosopher Sidney Morgenbesser, sitting in the audience, sarcastically replied, “Yeah, yeah.”)"

Comment: My favorite double negative is from the show Millennium. "Frank! You never don't know!"

Answer (score 12):

In English (formal English anyway), double negatives have the same effect as they do in math: two negatives make a positive (i.e. -1 x -1 = 1).

So saying "he's never not been in the family" means "there has never been a time when he was not part of the family," or more simply, "he's always been in the family".

Used like that, it is grammaticality correct.

The cases that are ungrammatical and make people sound uneducated is when they use a double negative when they don't mean to make it positive. For example, "he ain't got no time". That sentence technically means "he has time", but that's not what is meant. Every native speaker would understand what is truly meant, but it is never taught as correct.

Comment: This is a frequently repeated statement, which is however almost entirely false. It is simply not true that in English, two negatives make a positive. With suitable context and emphasis, they can do so (Pinker gives the example of "Try as I might, I can't get **no** satisfaction from ... "); and your example also works (mostly because "never not" is not a collocation in those dialects which do allow double negatives). But every English speaker (unless they're being deliberately perverse) will understand "He ain't got no time", so it is simply false that it means "He has time".

Comment: I know "He ain't got no time" means "He doesn't have time" as well as "I won't do you no good" means "I won't do you good" but in my example the poster could have said "always" instead of "never not."

Comment: @ColinFine I can agree that some people would say that if it's generally understood, then it's correct. However, I would also argue that anyone who cares about being grammatically correct would not use a double negative to convey a negative. It would not be received well if used in any formal setting (like a formal speech, or a cover letter when applying to a job), unless clearly meant as a joke.

Comment: @GabrielLuci: I mostly agree with you. But I take "correct" as a purely _social_ judgment: not following the rules of so-called grammar is exactly like not dressing appropriately. But appropriate dress for an interview is not appropriate dress for the beach. And appropriate grammar for an interview may not be appropriate grammar for hanging out with your mates. It's when people attach value judgments to these distinctions, and believe, or imply, that people who don't follow the rules are infrerior, that I get annoyed.

Comment: @ColinFine You're right: correctness is a social judgement. Because of that, people learning English should be taught what is socially considered to be correct. So yes, someone new to English should be taught that some uses of double-negatives are not intended to be positive, but they should also know that using that construct themselves carries a social stigma.

Comment: @ColinFine People seem to generally consider that to be slang usage though, as opposed to proper grammar.  Everybody understands it that way but would still put a red line through it on a test if it's meant positively.

Comment: @Panzercrisis: yes, but for me the opposition of "slang" and "proper grammar" is objectionably value-laden. That is why I say "standard" and "non-standard".

Comment: Correctness is a power game. And if you want power, you'd better learn it. The rest is a matter for linguists (who do not judge people's speech). Incorrectly used double negatives will not take you far. Knowing how to wield them correctly, on the other hand, might get you somewhere...in terms of social hierarchies....I call this stuff; The Way of the World (like the Congreve play)....

Comment: @ManuelHernandez While the [law of the excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle) is valid in formal logic, it's not universally valid for English sentences. Stating "she is attractive" and stating "she is unattractive" do not exhaustively enumerate the possibilities (she could have an attractiveness that is not worth mentioning). Thus "she is not unattractive" is not ungrammatical. Similarly, "never not been" is not identical to "always been". The implication and emphasis of the sentence shifts to the negative state, rather than being on the positive state.

Comment: I get it "never not been" is grammatical. However I think that "never not been" is same as "always been" at least it implies a sentiment that it has "always been" thus they're equal.

Comment: You probably be referring to "not never" as in someone would say to you "you have never been on time" you would reply "not never but sometimes" that's totally different than "I have never not been late" I hope I'm correct since English is not my first language.

Comment: Or a full answer "I have not never been on time but I have been sometimes" that would be something like "I have not always been on time but I have sometimes" or "I have not always been late but I have been late sometimes" or even "I have not always been late but sometimes"

Comment: I hear tons of thousands of Americans use double negatives in "informal" way.....

Answer (score 9):

As in many languages, negative sentences in English select certain words (called "negative polarity items") and disallow others. A particular set of negative polarity terms is the "any" series: in negative sentences and questions, "some" words are generally replaced by "any" words, eg

> *I found somebody.* vs *I didn't find anybody.*

In many dialects of English, the negative polarity terms are "no" words instead of (or as well as) "any" words, so:

> *I didn't find nobody.*

These forms are not used in any Standard Englishes, and so the idea has grown up in the last couple of hundred years that they are "wrong". As is often the case with forms which some people use but which the establishment judges to be "wrong", a spurious rationalisation has been invented for that judgment (rather than admit that it is an arbitrary rule): that "I didn't find nobody" *means* "I found somebody". This rationalisation has its intellectual base in logic (but much language is not logical) - that it is false can be seen by the fact that even English speakers who do not use such forms themselves always understand them (unless they are being deliberately perverse): thus both the speaker and the hearer understand "I didn't find nobody" to mean "I didn't find anybody", and it is false to claim that it "means" "I found somebody".

However, while it is not true in general that "a double negative means an affirmative", it can do, given suitable context and prosody. Stephen Pinker gives the example "Try as I might, I must admit that I can't get **no** satisfaction from this", where it clearly means "I do get some satisfaction".

Your example is another case where the negatives do cancel out, and I think the reason is that the order of negatives does not allow for another interpretation. If I heard "He hasn't never been in the family", I would take that (special prosody or context aside) as a non-standard form of "He hasn't ever been in the family", with the non-standard negative polarity term "never" replacing the standard "ever". But what we have here is "he's never not been in the family", with "never" preceding "not". That is not a position where a negative polarity term is expected, so it is not a non-standard version of anything. Thus it can only be interpreted as a negative in the scope of a negative: it is grammatical, and both have independent meanings.

Note that they do not just cancel out: it doesn't mean "He has been in the family": it means something like "He has always been in the family", but with an added connotation, something like "contrary to what has been suggested".

Comment: I have never not agreed that never not is grammatical it's just that I had my doubts.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to other great answers (I upvoted both of them), I would suggest several sentences for your thought. As you know, I am not a native English speaker, but the following sentences helped me a great deal understanding so called "double negative sentences".

> 1. I ain't (don't) got (have) **no** money.

The double negative (DN) is used for emphasis. It means *I don't have money. I really mean it*.

> 2. It won't do you **no** good.

The DN is also used for emphasis. It means *It won't do you any good* or *There is no good doing this*.

> 3. I can't **not** think about you.

The DN is used to make a positive sentence (We can also say it is used for emphasis). It means *I always think about you* or *I can't stop thinking about you*.

When there is a boyfriend visiting his girlfriend after six months of not seeing each other and he says, "I can't not think about you," what would you think he means?

It all depends on situation and the [following link](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-double-negatives.html) has more examples for your further reading and understanding. One thing to remember is the DN doesn't always make a positive sentence.

Comment: Good answer; except that in 1 and 2 there does not need to be any special emphasis. For some people "I ain't got no money" is the normal unmarked form, with no special emphasis, corresponding to standard English "I haven't got any money" (mainly BrE) or "I don't have any money" (mainly AmE)

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering, as many people say, it is obviously grammatically "incorrect", **however**, when we see this in the light of the "pronunciation", these double negatives,

such as

> I din't find nobody.

or

> I ain't do nothing.
>
> Coundn't find him nowhere.. so on and on,

aren't they easier to "pronounce" than the "standard English"?

Comment: Maybe, but there is no clear reason why they should be. They are simply an alternative form which has never been adopted into the standard, so people who believe in "wrong" call them "wrong".